# Grails Facebook Login deployed on cloud foundry doesn't work

Tags: facebook, grails, spring-security, cloud-foundry

I have the grails application integrated and redirects working well with facebook plugin. I deployed my grails application on cloud foundry, the facebook redirect doesn't work. The http traffic shows no jSessionId being set on redirect to my web site. Instead, there is a SessionProxyFilter_SessionId cookie being set. Can anyone please help how to get around this and make it work? Thanks!

---

### Updated

I found this error in the logs, looks like it could be my config associated to grails spring security + Facebook.  This happens only when I deploy to cloud foundry, not on localhost. My configuration on Facebook developer a/c is correct - has proper web site url.
Can someone please shed some light?

---

ERROR databasesession.GormPersisterService  - com.the6hours.grails.springsecurity.facebook.FacebookAccessToken
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.the6hours.grails.springsecurity.facebook.FacebookAccessToken
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
    at grails.plugin.databasesession.PersistentSessionAttributeValue.setValue(PersistentSessionAttributeValue.groovy:28)
    at grails.plugin.databasesession.GormPersisterService.setAttribute(GormPersisterService.groovy:76)
    at grails.plugin.databasesession.SessionProxy.setAttribute(SessionProxy.java:98)
    at org.grails.jaxrs.web.JaxrsFilter.doFilterInternal(JaxrsFilter.java:46)
    at grails.plugin.databasesession.SessionProxyFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionProxyFilter.java:51)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Answer (score 1):

finally resolved it - do this in config.groovy

grails.plugin.databasesession.enabled = false